# Does ADA have any credit features built into it?

Tags: ada, proof-of-stake

Are there any feature of Cardano ADA or its ecosystem that make borrowing against ADA held easier or better than other cryptocurrencies?

Will all credit require that an application be developed to support it?

Answer (score 1):

This is really up to the users (or dApps) on Cardano, but in order to get credit you normally have to provide a collateral. The lender wants to make sure they are getting their money back. Getting credit without putting down a collateral will at least require some form of identification and proof of trustworthiness. Simply having an account/address on Cardona won't be sufficient because anyone create those indefinitely. So in the end it depends on what kind of solutions will be deployed to Cardano and how they are integrated to identity providers all around the world.

Answer (score 1):

[Celcius](https://celsius.network/) has already committed to integrating Cardano's ADA, which will let you borrow against your ADA for USD or a stable coin. I don't have a timeline when ADA will be implemented, my guess is after Alonzo.